# Qt EventFilter - Once Event consumed by event filter, control never returns back to MouseArea

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to filter out touch events from multiple touch points. So have installed an EventFilter that react and consumes events with multiple touch points else to return false. When I ran the sample qml, the mouse click initially works with single touch on window and I do multiple touch on the window the event get consumed by the event filter(as expected) but then when I do single touch on window again the MouseArea never gets the event. I have also tried with debug on return of event filter when indeed returns false for single touch point. **Qt Version-> 5.9.4 MingW 32 bit on Windows**

```
bool MultipleTouchFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() <<"Object name " << obj->objectName();
    QTouchEvent *  eventTouch = dynamic_cast< QTouchEvent * >(event);
    if(eventTouch != nullptr && eventTouch->touchPoints().count() > 1)
      return true;
    else
      return false; 
}
```

I've installed this filter to the QCoreApplication

```
QCoreApplication *app = QCoreApplication::instance();
    if (app) {
        app->installEventFilter(m_multitouchFilter);
    }
```

main.qml

```
Window {
    objectName: "main window"
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    MouseArea{
        objectName: "MouseArea"
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Single touch ")
        }
    }
}
```